# How do I use this new extension for chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So I am trying to use this: https://github.com/Banksy404/Chart.Bands.js

and I have this url for my code:
'''
 script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/521837/Chart.Bands.js">

but it is too old, and I would like a newer version. Do I have to make a file or something?

Answer (score 0):

So if you make an account through AWS and make a bucket, copy the code and copy the path into your code.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html